# How to run tensorflow object detection api (model_main_tf2) from code?

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection, object-detection-api

I want to run a training with the tensorflow object detection api. In the command line I can use the

`python model_main_tf2.py --pipeline_config_path=path/to/pipeline.config --model_dir=path/to/trainedModel`

But how can I start it from code?

```
model_main_tf2.FLAGS.pipeline_config_path = pipeline_config_path
model_main_tf2.FLAGS.model_dir = model_path
tf.compat.v1.app.run(model_main_tf2.main)
```

This is working, but the tf.compat.v1.app.run() calls the main function by using sys.exit(main). However I do not want, that the system exits.

How can I solve this?

Or maybe, how can I get around the usage of model_main_tf2 and the app.run()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `sys.exit(...)` basically raises `SystemExit` you may just catch the [`SystemExit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#SystemExit):

```py
try:
  tf.compat.v1.app.run(model_main_tf2.main)
except SystemExit:
  pass

# cool stuff happening here!
```